# Magento send custom mail to custom person after Place Order

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, transactional-mail

Magento How to send a mail to a custom person after Place order

I tried below code in `observer.php` but it's not working

```
 <?php 

class Manoj_Customemail_Model_Observer{
     public function customMail($event)
    {
        $order = $event->getOrder();
       //add your mail send code here

        $html="put your html content here blah blah";
$mail = Mage::getModel('core/email');
$mail->setToName('Your Name');
$mail->setToEmail('mymail@gmail.com');
$mail->setBody('Mail Text / Mail Content');
$mail->setSubject('Mail Subject');
$mail->setFromEmail('Sender Mail Id');
$mail->setFromName("Msg to Show on Subject");
$mail->setType('html');// YOu can use Html or text as Mail format

try {
$mail->send();

    }
}

}
```

**confix.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
      <modules>
        <Manoj_Customemail>
          <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Manoj_Customemail>
      </modules>
      <global>
        <helpers>
          <customemail>
            <class>Manoj_Customemail_Helper</class>
          </customemail>
        </helpers>

 <models>
            <customemail>
                <class>Manoj_Customemail_Model</class>
            </customemail>
        </models>



         <events>
                <sales_order_place_after>
                    <observers>
                        <sales_order_observer>
                            <type>singleton</type>
                            <class>Manoj_Customemail_Model_Observer</class>
                            <method>customMail</method>
                        </sales_order_observer>
                    </observers>
                </sales_order_place_after>
            </events>

      </global>
    </config>
```

After Place order it redirect to cart page

Comment: do you have a fix custom id or it may be change ?

Comment: Sorry i am not getting

Comment: try `public function customMail(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)` in place of `public function customMail($event)`

Comment: Still same it redirect to shopping cart only

Answer (score 0):

You need to observe below event

```
       <events>
            <sales_order_place_after>
                <observers>
                    <sales_order_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Namespace_Modulename_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>customMail</method>
                    </sales_order_observer>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_after>
        </events>
```

Create your observer as below:

```
class Namespace_Modulename_Model_Observer{
     public function customMail($event)
    {
        $order = $event->getOrder();
       //add your mail send code here

    }
}
```

Comment: check my updated question

Answer (score 0):

You can create a simple magento extension that contains an observer on sales_order_place_after event and then you can use zend_mail to send a custom email. Something like

```
$fromEmail = "from@example.com"; // sender email address
$fromName = "John Doe"; // sender name

$toEmail = "to@example.com"; // recipient email address
$toName = "Mark Doe"; // recipient name

$body = "This is Test Email!"; // body text
$subject = "Test Subject"; // subject text

$mail = new Zend_Mail();        

$mail->setBodyText($body);

$mail->setFrom($fromEmail, $fromName);

$mail->addTo($toEmail, $toName);

$mail->setSubject($subject);

try {
    $mail->send();
}
catch(Exception $ex) {
    // I assume you have your custom module. 
    // If not, you may keep 'customer' instead of 'yourmodule'.
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')
        ->addError(Mage::helper('yourmodule')
        ->__('Unable to send email.'));
}
```

This could be a quick fix but I recommend to create a custom email template in magento. Maybe [Inchoo's custom email template](http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-custom-emails/) post can get you started

Comment: Where i need to add email code

Comment: Create a new Magento extension. If you need help, have a look [here](https://www.ashsmith.io/2012/12/making-use-of-observers-in-magento/). At Step 2 change <sales_order_place_before> with <sales_order_place_after>. You email code will go in Step 4 public function example($observer)

Comment: check my updated question

Comment: You will have to learn how Magento modules work. It's very clear that you are missing Model and code is incorrect. If you follow the instructions/steps from my previous comment you should be able to do it.

Comment: sorry i missed  Model code still same